# Possible ipv6 issue with subdomain on Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I'm delegating DNS resolution for a subdomain to Route 53 on AWS. Initially everything worked fine, but after a few days name resolution stopped working in the browser and using nslookup. Using simpledns.com for troubleshooting, this is what seems to happen:

A request is sent to the registrar for my main domain, which correctly responds with the four Route 53 name servers I've configured for the subdomain.

The name for one of the Route 53 name servers is then resolved, and the result is both an ipv4 address and an ipv6 address.

Next, the ipv6 address to the Route 53 name server is called, but this fails with the following message:

"Error sending request: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used"

It then tries with the ipv4 address instead, and this successfully returns the A record I've specified in Route 53.

My idea is that when running nslookup (or name resolution in the browser), it fails when trying to contact the Route 53 name server over ipv6, and doesn't retry with the ipv4 address. Don't know how to confirm this though.

What might cause this behavior? Any ideas how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the hostname in question?

Comment: Give the domain name concerned and use `dig` instead of `nslookup` for DNS diagnostics. The error message you quote is not a DNS error message.